# Connect mined blocks with various addresses

Tags: alternatives

From code:

```
 // Create coinbase tx
 CTransaction txNew;
 txNew.vin.resize(1);
 txNew.vin[0].prevout.SetNull();
 txNew.vout.resize(1);
 CPubKey pubkey;
 if (!reservekey.GetReservedKey(pubkey))
     return NULL;
 txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey << pubkey << OP_CHECKSIG;

 // Add our coinbase tx as first transaction
 pblock->vtx.push_back(txNew);
 pblocktemplate->vTxFees.push_back(-1); // updated at end
 pblocktemplate->vTxSigOps.push_back(-1); // updated at end
```

How I can connect mined blocks with various addresses in base58? Not only with miner address.

I want send part of mined value to one address (developer fund), different of miner address.

add vtx[1]?
Only check it in connectblock and createnewblock functions?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking: Is this question about how to send the mining reward to more than one address?

Comment: Yes. Send part of getblockvalue() to selected address.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer but I might be able to point you in the right direction:

It seems like you have:

```
CBlockTemplate* CreateNewBlock(const CScript& scriptPubKeyIn)
```

So you're taking a [CScript](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/script_8h.html)  as a parameter. Some additional relevant links.  I think you would either use that to create multiple outputs, or you would use

```
txNew.vout[1];
```

- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions#general_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_output_of_a_transaction_-_Txout
- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script
- https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/script_8cpp.html
- https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/class_c_transaction.html
  (and follow the links to CTxIn/CTxOut from there

Also see how they do it here:
 - https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/miner__tests_8cpp_source.html